# Equals not working on custom class

Tags: c#, list, overriding, equals

I know that this question has been asked a few times for C#, I've gone through a few different examples, and starting to loose my mind.

I have a custom class I'm using for a list and am attempting to compare two instances of it to determine if they are equal, and eventually look to see if there are duplicates (but first things first).

Its a simple type class just holding a few string items. When I attempt to compare the two lists using either "==" or .Equals() it always returns false.
The examples I have seen use the Equals override that seems to be coming from the same class. This is its own class, and I"m trying to compare them in a different class. I created a test project to to work on the Equals problem for simplicity. I have been checking against just one field to see if I can get it to work at all, with no luck.

Oddly enough, even when setting break points anywhere in the either equals method, or gethashcode method. The debugger in VS 2015 does not stop the code, like the methods are not being called at all.

If anyone could help with what i'm doing wrong, that would be great!

```
    class TagContainer : IEquatable<TagContainer>
      {
    public int idNo { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public string artists { get; set; }
    public string album { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }

    public TagContainer()

    {
        idNo = idNo;
        filePath = filePath;
        artists = artists;
        album = album;
        genre = genre;
        title = title;
        year = year;
    }



    public bool Equals(TagContainer obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        return this.filePath.Equals(filePath);
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;

        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        TagContainer tc = (TagContainer)obj;
        return filePath == tc.filePath;


    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = 13;
            var myStrHashCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) ?
                 filePath.GetHashCode() : 0;
            return hashCode * myStrHashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have test from that creates the lists and then checks to see if they are equal.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<TagContainer> tc1 = new List<TagContainer>();
    List<TagContainer> tc2 = new List<TagContainer>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addtoTC1();
        addtoTC2();

        textBox1.Text = tc1.Equals(tc2).ToString();

    }

    public void addtoTC1()
    {
        TagContainer tc = new TagContainer()
        {
            idNo = 1,
            filePath = "file1",
            artists = "artist 1",
            album = "album1",
            genre = "genre1",
            title = "title1",
            year = "2016"
        };
        tc1.Add(tc);

        TagContainer tg = new TagContainer()
        {
            idNo = 1,
            filePath = "file2",
            artists = "artist 2",
            album = "album2",
            genre = "genre2",
            title = "title2",
            year = "2016"
        };

        tc1.Add(tg);

    }

    public void addtoTC2()
    {
        TagContainer tc = new TagContainer()
        {
            idNo = 1,
            filePath = "file1",
            artists = "artist 1",
            album = "album1",
            genre = "genre1",
            title = "title1",
            year = "2016"
        };
        tc2.Add(tc);

        TagContainer tg = new TagContainer()
        {
            idNo = 1,
            filePath = "file2",
            artists = "artist 2",
            album = "album2",
            genre = "genre2",
            title = "title2",
            year = "2016"
        };

        tc2.Add(tg);

    }



}
```

Comment: Honestly I'm a bit surprised that you are not getting a compiler warning on the `public bool Equals(TagContainer tc)` method.  Even though you have supplied an overridden `Equals(object obj)` I would recommend you only use the override to keep this much more readable and ensure that you are only using one overload of the `Equals` function.

Comment: Also you are violating the definition of `Equals`.  You cast the object to your type, and then only check equality on one property of the object?  I would be a saaaaad panda if I had to consume that via some API.  Instead you should be returning a boolean that checks if the entire object's contents are equal in value.  That is the general use case for overriding `Equals`.

Comment: @Even: The `public bool Equals(TagContainer tc)` method is necessary to implement the `IEquatable<TagContainer>` interface, which is useful to avoid boxing for generic collections. Additionally, I disagree on having to check every field to implement a proper `Equals` method.  What makes 2 object instances equal is a business decision that everyone gets to make however they see fit. Maybe you only need to check the primary keys of the entity, that can be perfectly ok.

Comment: @sstan I missed the implementation of `IEquatable<T>` my bad on that one.  And I agree with you sentiment regarding business decisions, I was more concerned with him checking `filePath` rather than `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer stated, you didn't check for sequence similarity. But your equals method also is with a flaw. You are comparing to the same object in the first equals method:

```
public bool Equals(TagContainer obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;

    return this.filePath.Equals(obj.filePath); // <-- here you were comparing to this
}
```

Comment: That's a problem, to be sure, but does not explain why the equality comparison always returns _`false`_. This bug would cause it to always return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

For the people that might land on this page looking for help, keep in mind that `public bool override Equals(Obj obj)` only works for `fooVar1.Equals(fooVar2)` if you want to use the equality operator (`==`) you need `public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b)` and its required counterpart `public static bool operator !=(Foo a, Foo b)`.

Hope this saves you some time.